# Fun with Powerball history. What probability theories apply?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference

I wanted to play around with [probability theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) and see if I find any [statistical inferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) from the [Powerball lottery history](http://www.powerball.com/powerball/pb_nbr_history.asp) going back to 11/1/1997.  What theories could I apply besides simple linear and multiple regression analysis?

I have broken the numbers down based on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerball) description of the game with a simple [console program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/26130/13425).

Comment: relevant: http://www.lottery-analysis.com/powerball-number-patterns.php

Comment: @vadim123 Time is very relevant.  Thank you, I think I can work this into a regression model.

Comment: @CommonerG I am positive it follows the concept of [statistical randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inferenc) but when doing a simple linear regression  with the fourth draw being held as the dependent and the fifth as the independent; correlation becomes slightly more significant. Understandably so based on the diminishing pool of numbers. But it would be interesting to see what other inferences I could make.  I just want to play with numbers of interest in an area of math that I need to know better.

Answer (score 3):

Studying the statistical properties of the Powerball draws is likely not going to turn up anything interesting. I wouldn't play Powerball, but I would bet on the fact that the numbers are uniformly drawn.

However, there might be something interesting to learn about how people *play* Powerball. If one knew about how people tend to select numbers, it would be possible to take advantage of this by playing combinations that are less likely to end in a shared prize. The ideal data-set for this would be the actual combinations selected by people.

However, short of this, it would be possible to extract some information about patterns-of-play using the actual draws from the data set you have provided along with any data you can get on number of matches, prizes paid, etc. (tickets sold or at least jackpot size would be useful here as well).

Comment: I like the idea of choosing numbers that are less likely to share prize. Certainly the data you suggest could make for some more interesting inferences.